# "Remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: web-services

While accessing a wsdl file as webservice I am getting this Exception. "Remote name could not be resolved"

Answer (score 5):

That could mean:

- you don't have any connection to that host
- something is blocking your access (firewall etc.)
- the address in the WSDL might be a local DEV address which doesn't work for production
- your machine you're running on is in a DNS zone without name resolution (don't laugh - I'm dealing with that kind of stuff every day....)

You can check:

- Can you ping the address given?
- Can you navigate to that address in a browser?

Comment: How Can I resolve if my machine is in a DNS zone without name resolution???